# How to return multiple values without it being cast as an array?

Tags: powershell, return, arguments

In powershell, I have a function where I want to return multiple values and use said values as positional arguments to a second function. Unfortunately, it is returning the group of values as an array. How do I avoid this?

Additionally, can I avoid this behavior without introducing new variables? I understand I could pass the returned array to a variable and splat it as arguments to the function, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Code that demonstrates the issue I'm having is as follows:

```bsh
function Return-Values{
    return "One", "Two", "Three"
}
function Print-Args{
    param($One,$Two,$Three)
    Write-Host "1" $One
    Write-Host "2" $Two
    Write-Host "3" $Three
}
Print-Args (Return-Values)
```

The output is:

```
1 One Two Three
2 
3
```

I expect the output to be:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
```

Comment: Please _edit the question, do not add a comment_ and explain what you are trying to achieve. As far as I know, most if not all programming languages will return a single value from a function. Returning multiple values requires tricks like returning a structure, array or object. Pointers and references work too. Even languages like Python and Swift that advertise returning multiple values really return a single object. Syntax sugar makes it easy to access its contents so that it looks like multiple values.

Comment: @vonPryz Could you clarify whether I have inadequately explained what I wish to achieve, or whether it is not possible within the constraints I've set?

I'm not entirely sure how to state it beyond how it is written in the introduction: "_I have a function where I want to return multiple values and use said values as positional arguments to a second function_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [About Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6). I was not able to get the function work as you wished. The following example does what you wish with one line more code. Maybe someone else knows another way.

```
function Return-Values{
     return "One", "Two", "Three"
}

[System.Array]$InputArray = Return-Values #Get the input values as an array

function Print-Args{
    param($One,$Two,$Three)
    Write-Host "1" $One
    Write-Host "2" $Two
    Write-Host "3" $Three
}

Print-Args @InputArray #Use splatting for the input parameters
```